# Error: Please use column names for `x` when using caret() for logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression, r-caret

I'd like to build a logistic regression model using the caret package.

This is my code.

```
library(caret)
df <- data.frame(response = sample(0:1, 200, replace=TRUE),  predictor = rnorm(200,10,45)) 

outcomeName <-"response"
predictors <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% outcomeName)]
index <- createDataPartition(df$response, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
trainSet <- df[ index,]
testSet <- df[-index,]

model_glm <- train(trainSet[,outcomeName], trainSet[,predictors], method='glm', family="binomial", data = trainSet)
```

I get the error `Error: Please use column names for x`.

I receive the same error when I replace `trainSet[,predictors]` with the column name `predictors`.

Comment: `?caret` mentions `x` : *must have column names*. If you use `trainSet[,predictors]` where `predictors` is one column, you will get a vector with no names. Try with `trainSet[predictors]`

Comment: You're a boss..

Comment: If you specify the x and y parameter values, the data parameter does not have to be given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately R has a nasty behavior when subsetting just one column like `df[,1]` to change outcome to a `vector` and as you have only one predictor you encountered this feature.  You can preserve results as `data.frame` by either

```
trainSet[,predictors, drop = FALSE]
```

or

```
trainSet[predictors]
```

BTW. there are two additional issues with the code:

1. First argument should be predictors, not response
2. For logistic regression with `caret` you need response to be a `factor`

The full code should be:

```
library(caret)
df <- data.frame(response = sample(0:1, 200, replace=TRUE),  
                 predictor = rnorm(200,10,45)) 

df$response <- as.factor(df$response)

outcomeName <-"response"
predictors <- names(df)[!(names(df) %in% outcomeName)]
index <- createDataPartition(df$response, p=0.75, list=FALSE)
trainSet <- df[ index,]
testSet <- df[-index,]

model_glm <- train(trainSet[predictors], trainSet[[outcomeName]], method='glm', family="binomial", data = trainSet)
```

*changed `trainSet[,outcomeName]` to `trainSet[[outcomeName]]` for more explicit transformation to `vector`

Comment: If I have simulated a data matrix as xtrain, a vector as ytrain, my code ```train(xtrain, ytrain, method='glmnet', trControl=cv5, tuneLength=10) ``` does not work. What can I do here as I cannot specify the predictors?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

```
`head(iris)
xx <- iris[,-5]
yy <- iris[,5]
rf.imp <- train(x = xx, y = yy, method = "rf",  data = iris); rf.imp`
```