# Multinomial stepwise forward selection

Tags: r, r-caret, nnet

For my research I want to do multinomial logistic stepwise forward selection (despite its drawbacks). To do this I run the following example code:

```
x1=sample(1:100,10,replace=T)
x2=sample(1:100,10,replace=T)
x3=sample(1:100,10,replace=T)
x4=sample(1:100,10,replace=T)
x5=sample(1:100,10,replace=T)
x=as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5))
y=as.data.frame(c(0,0,2,3,0,0,3,1,0,0))
xy=as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
names(xy)[6]="y"
beststep=train(multinom(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5,data=xy), method="glmStepAIC", direction="forward", k=log(10))
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Error: Please use column names for `x
```

The columns of the data frame xy are all named. What can be the problem here and how can it be solved?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54963790/error-please-use-column-names-for-x-when-using-caret-for-logistic-regressio

Comment: In general, `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` is an anti-pattern. Use `data.frame(...)` instead. In this case, it doesn't matter because all your data is the same type, but `cbind()` converts to a matrix first so if you are mixing string and numeric (or even integer and double) data types, the `cbind` matrix conversion will mess things up.

Comment: True, but it does not solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the last row from

```
beststep=train(multinom(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x4+x5,data=xy), method="glmStepAIC", direction="forward", k=log(3562))
```

to

```
beststep=train(y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x4+x5,data=xy, method="glmStepAIC", direction="forward", k=log(3562))
```

I got the result without error. Maybe you have specific reason to include a model in (`multinom`), but `train` function doesn't accept a model as first paramter.

Comment: This is just a pooled model and not a multinomial model, which I want to use for my forward selection.

Answer (score 0):

Says in the `multinom` function that the response is a factor. Whilst it can be an integer for `multinom`, the only example used with train I see here https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/multinom.R, treats it as a factor in the iris data.

This works for me, is it what you need?

```
xy$y <- as.factor(xy$y)
beststep=train(y~.,
               data=xy, 
               method="multinom",
               direction="forward", k=log(3562))
```

you have `x4` twice in your model formula. Can use `.` if using all regressors

Comment: I use ```method=glmstepAIC``` because I want my stepwise selection procedure to be based on the BIC (that's why k=log(n)). When this is removed, the stepwise selection is not based on the BIC anymore (on what is it based?). That is why I want to leave it in and therefore your solution is not entirely what I am seeking for

Comment: I was also looking into ```metric=BIC```, but R reports ```The metric "BIC" was not in the result set. Accuracy will be used instead.``` so that also does not work.

Comment: and `stepAIC`? I'm assuming its the metric that `glmStepAIC` is based on

Comment: hmm I tried it with `stepAIC` and it didn't error. The `metric` component in `?train` is the metric used for optimising the model. Can also be set with `summaryFunction` in `trainControl`.

Comment: For my example, it does not give the error indeed but it does for the data I want to apply the method to. However, it does not work for the example too because when you set the metric to ```"Accuracy"``` or to ```"stepAIC"``` it gives the same results without variables that are selected. I was trying ```trainControl``` yesterday but I could not figure out how that would work for my example. Do you have an idea how this would work?

Comment: Not much, sorry. You would need to write a function similar to the format of `multiClassSummary`. It currently either allows `Accuracy` or `Keppa` as the metrics of choice. I don't have experience with building my own classification function. It says what the inputs are so if you know the formula maybe you can write the function by hand and put in the `trainControl()` function